# numpy.all() and empty arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I noticed that `numpy.all(np.array([]))` evaluates to `True`. I could not find any documentation for this particular case. Is this an undefined behavior or is `all` guaranteed to evaluate to `True` for empty arrays?

Comment: The Python list equivalent notes: `If the iterable is empty, return True.`

Comment: You could submit a documentation patch to numpy.

Answer (score 2):

NumPy is consistent with the logic of Python lists:

```
>>> all([])
True
>>> any([])
False
```

And both follow the rules of formal logic, which might mean there is no need to document this as a special case. Example: unicorns do not exist, so the list of unicorns is `[]`

- The statement "all unicorns are red" is true. It spells out as "if X is a unicorn, then X is red", which is true for all objects since they are not unicorns.
- The statement "some unicorns are red" is false, because it asserts the existence of at least one red unicorn.

More on Wikipedia: [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).